# $\frac{d\Phi^{-1}(y)}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dy}[\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(y))]}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

If $\Phi(y)$ is a monotonic decreasing function is true that

$$\frac{d\Phi^{-1}(y)}{dy} = \frac{1}{\Phi'(\Phi^{-1}(y))}$$

If so, how?

It works for $y = \Phi(x) = e^{-x}, \quad \Phi^{-1}(y) = -log(y), \quad \frac{d\Phi^{-1}(y)}{dy} = \frac{-1}{y}, \quad $

Comment: Did you test it out on a few functions whose inverses are simple to get? If so include examples...

Comment: I think that's true for all invertible functions.

Answer (score 1):

use the fact $$ \Phi\left(\Phi^{-1}(y)\right) = y$$ and the chain rule for the derivative.

Comment: It's $\Phi ' (x) $

Comment: @Abel I was writing the same answer and saw that someone gave a down vote here.  I don't get it, but glad you beat me to the post - I'll give yours a +1

Comment: @Dr.MV, these down voters, they are hard to understand. thanks for your upvote.

Comment: @abel  I know.  Someone tries to help another and get punished.  And my pleasure to neutralize the wrong doer.

Comment: I think the downvote is because this fact doesn't apply to the question.

Comment: Of course it applies. If $f(g(y)) = y$, applying the chain rule gives $y' = g'(y) f'(g(y))$ so $g'(y) = y'/f'(g(y))$. But $g(y) = f^{(-1)}(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $${\phi'(y)} = \frac{1}{f'(x)}$$ is a well known theorem for all invertible functions where $\phi(y) = f^{-1}(y)$. More on it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Inverses_in_calculus).