# Why is $\frac{d\phi^{-1}(y)}{dy}=\frac{1}{\phi'\phi^{-1}(y)} $

Tags: calculus

Why is $\frac{d\phi^{-1}(y)}{dy}=\frac{1}{\phi'\phi^{-1}(y)} $.

The way I had done it:

$\phi\phi^{-1}(y)=y$.
$\frac{d\phi\phi^{-1}}{dy}=1$
$\phi^{-1}\frac{d\phi}{dy}+\phi\frac{d\phi^{-1}}{dy}=1 $
$ \frac{d\phi^{-1}}{dy}=\frac{1-\phi^{-1}\phi'}{\phi}$

Comment: This isn't multiplying of two functions, it's composition!

Comment: Could you give me a little bit more detail .Thank you very much

Comment: Do you know about the composition of two functions?

Comment: Oh yes, I get it now. Thank you, I was half asleep.

Comment: OK. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule for more details.

Comment: Or maybe [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273678/fracd-phi-1ydy-frac1-fracddy-phi-phi-1y?rq=1) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorthand proof using your notation:

$\phi (\phi^{-1} (y) ) = y$

$\dfrac{d}{dy}$$\phi (\phi^{-1} (y) ) = \dfrac{d}{dy} y$

$\phi '(\phi^{-1}(y))\dfrac{d}{dy}\phi^{-1}(y) = 1$

$\dfrac{d}{dy}\phi^{-1}(y) = \dfrac{1}{\phi '(\phi^{-1}(y))}$

Comment: Note that this proof assumes differentiability of $\phi^{-1}$ at $y$ since chain rule is used and chain rule only works for differentiable function.

Comment: The proof that proves differentiability is usually a direct one, or based on Caratheodory theorem.

Comment: @LiChunMin For differentiablility, it’s enough that $\phi'$ not vanish at $\phi^{-1}(y)$. On the other hand, we couldn’t divide by $\phi'(\phi^{-1}(y))$ in the last step anyway if that were the case, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f^{-1}(x)$ be the inverse of injective $f$. Then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ in the domain by definition. Hence we get,

$$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(f(x))=\frac{d}{dx}x$$

The chain rule tells us that we must have the equality,

$$f^{-1}_x(f(x))f'(x)=1$$

For all $x$ in the domain. From which we find that,

$$f^{-1}_x(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$

In particular, letting $x=f^{-1}(u)$ gives.

$$f^{-1}_x(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

For $x$ in the range of $f$ so long as the quantities above exist and equality makes sense.